# Preg Match Apostrophe

Tags: php, regex

I have an input field (text area) that needs to allow apostrophe's. Here's what I have.

```
if (!empty($_POST["adv"]) && !preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9 \.,\?_/'!£\$%&*()+=\r\n-]+$#",$_POST["adv"])){
    $addErr = "Please use letters, numbers, and common punctuation only"; $valid = false;
}
if (!empty($_POST["adv"]) && mb_strlen($_POST["adv"], 'UTF-8') > 500){
    $addErr = "Ad must not exceed 500 characters"; $valid = false;
}
$add = htmlspecialchars($_POST['adv']);
```

If an apostrophe is included in the text input, the code breaks and doesn't update the database. If the text doesn't contain an apostrophe, the `preg match` validates accurately, and the database updates.

I've tried escaping, double escaping, and moving the apostrophe with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please specify what exactly "the code breaks" means, and show the part where you update the database. My guess is that you have an SQL injection issue and that you should use prepared statements with PDO to fix that.

Comment: "Code breaks", meaning inputs from all fields from same form do not update database.

Comment: @bcintegrity FYI, added a cleaned-up regex to my answer.

Comment: Maybe you strings that you are bringing in are including other types of ascii quotations. http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/quotes-test-utf-8.html

Comment: As Beat and zx81 suggested below, I need to use prepared statements. For the time being, I'm using str_replace("'","\'", $adv), which got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is not with the regex, but with the SQL statement itself: you should escape your DB queries properly, either by using a function like [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or, better yet, [prepared statements](http://php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Apostrophes are used to quote strings in SQL statements; if you have an unescaped apostrophe in your string, the whole query will break. See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) on how to properly escape your SQL statements – this is also a serious security risk for your site.

You've tried escaping the string with `htmlspecialchars`, which is fine for preventing XSS if you're outputting the string into an HTML context, but it is not the right tool for a DB context. Always escape your data with the right tool for the context you're inserting it into.

Comment: Somehow, I've been using `!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \.,\-\']*$/",$_POST["emp"])` successfully in another field to allow apostrope's. Prepared statements are in the works... Know of any good tutorials?

Comment: I've linked to the php.net documentation on prepared statements, they explain it quite nicely.

Comment: What you "said" makes sense. I was using similar validation earlier for an email form :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PDO, use the `quote()` method before your `INSERT`:

`$db->quote($mystring)...

or [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prepared-statement/info).

**Why is the insertion breaking down?**

It sounds to me like you are building an `INSERT` query by gluing various strings and bits of code. If one of these bits as a quote that is not escaped, the whole query has a new meaning and can no longer be parsed by MySQL.

**Tip**

With queries that break the code, **print** the query so you can see what is wrong. You may also want to dump it in a tool that can highlight MySQL syntax, such as SQLYog, HeidiSQL and others.

**Your Regex**

Apart from that, your regex can be cleaned up. This is equivalent to the regex you are using, but easier on the eyes:

```
$regex = "~^[\w .,?'!£$%&*()+=\r\n-]+$~";
```

1. The `\w` will match all letters, digits and the underscore character
2. Removed the backslash from the period and other chars that don't need to be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the regex. Yours is MUCH easier on the eyes!